# BiDi text not displayed properly in Delphi 7 when using RTL BiDi mode?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, right-to-left, bidi

In Delphi 7, drop a `TMemo` on a form and in the form's `OnCreate` handler enable RTL `BiDiMode` like this:

```
  SysLocale.MiddleEast := True;
  Application.BiDiMode := bdRightToLeft;
```

If you then load a text file containing BiDi text into the `TMemo` using `Lines.LoadFromFile`, the text will not be displayed correctly.

Let's have the following text in the text file (this is also the proper way to display it, for example when displayed by Notepad++ or MS Word):

```
!ד asd אב!ג
text... text2...
```

Here's how it's incorrectly *displayed* in the `TMemo`:

```
אב!ג asd ד!
...text... text2
```

Here's how this text is stored in the text file:

```
21 E3 20 61 73 64 20 E0 E1 21 E2 0D 0A
74 65 78 74 2E 2E 2E 20 74 65 78 74 32 2E 2E 2E
```

Here's just a *visualization* of how it's stored (the text would never be rendered that way anywhere, this is just for illustration):

```
!ד asd ג!בא
text... text2...
```

So, BiDi text is saved in alternating "blocks": (RTL block)(LTR block)(RTL block)(LTR block) etc. The storing order of the blocks from left to right is the same as the order of the blocks the way you see them (from left to right) when properly rendered. The storing order of the characters in every RTL block is the reverse of the viewing order of the characters in those blocks when properly displayed (see the *alef*, *bet*, *exclamation mark*, *gimel* block).

The text is actually properly rendered when RTL `BiDiMode` is NOT enabled (if the value of `SysLocale.MiddleEast` is `False` or the value of `BiDiMode` is `bdLeftToRight`).

This incorrect rendering happens in other controls that I tested (`TLabel`, `TCheckbox`, `TRadioButton`, etc.).

Looking at the incorrectly displayed text in the `TMemo` when RTL `BiDiMode` is enabled, I'm seeing that the order of the blocks is actually reversed. Also, any leading neutral characters (like `!`, `?`, `.`, etc.) become trailing ones and vice versa (e.g. the three dots after the text `text2`).

Looking into this problem, I believe the issue lies in Windows' [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and the `DT_RTLREADING` flag that is used when BiDi text is rendered. If I'm not mistaken, this function is used to render the text in most controls. Indeed, if you render a BiDi text on a Canvas using `DrawText` with the `DT_RTLREADING` flag, it will be rendered in the same incorrect way, and if you don't use `DT_RTLREADING`, it will be rendered correctly.

I made a descendant class of `TLabel`, overriding it's `Paint` procedure to never use `DT_RTLREADING` when rendering the text and this does fix the issue. However, fixing this issue for Windows controls like `TCheckbox`, `TRadioButton`, and `TButton` would not be that easy.

I also tried using `DrawTextEx` - the issue remains.
I also tried using a utf8 text file and `TTntMemo` (which uses `DrawTextW`) - the issue remains.

**So, my questions are: Is this a known issue? Why is it happening? If it is, is there a fix for it? Or am I doing something wrong here?**